# Unable to Mount 128GB Micro SDXC Storage Card

Tags: usb-drive, micro-sd, memory-card

Previously, I was able to read from and write to my 128GB Micro SDXC storage card, which is always removed from my computer correctly (i.e. using the "eject" option)... It is also removed from my cell phone correctly, because I switch my cell phone off before I remove the storage card.

Now however, when I try to mount my storage card in Ubuntu, I am told:

```
Unable to access "Phablet"

Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/gregoryopera/Phablet: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1003,gid=1003,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/gregoryopera/Phablet"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Nothing on my storage card has changed (i.e. it is the same format it has always been) and aside from the usual day-to-day updates, nothing on my computer has changed either...

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install exfat driver in LINUX to access the exFAT formatted partitions in linux

I took this [from this post](http://www.pctips4u.com/2013/04/mount-exfat-in-linux.html), please see that for more information.

In Ubuntu, you have to add a PPA and then install it.
In ubuntu, open the terminal and type the following :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
```

In Ubuntu, I use the following command to install it successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
```

Now you will have the exFAT driver installed in your LINUX. Reboot your system and use your exFAT drive like every other drives.

Comment: But why did I not need to do this a week ago? It's not like I've changed distros or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has upgraded...

Comment: @GregoryOpera I don't think anyone can tell you why this started happening, there are just to many variables in the equation, however, the most common issue seems to be incorrect removal of the card, from phone or PC, I know you said you remove cards correctly but we all make mistakes.