# Sandisk Extreme 128gb XC is not recognised

Tags: mount, realtek, sd-card

I'm trying to mount 128gb Sandisk Extreme and so far I failed. The SD card is not recognised (not listed by `sudo parted-ls`). What is more, the different card is fully recognised and automounted (not xc).

**My card reader is**

```
Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
```

**My Laptop is**

```
XPS 15 9570
```

Since I have a dual boot I can confirm that the card works perfectly fine under windows. I also tried to google for it, but nowhere I can find the solution for the problem.

**In case you ask:**

Yes I did

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

and also checked this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752099/sandisk-extreme-pro-sdxc-128gb-wont-mount) but as you know the sd card is not even listed when using `fdisk -l` or `sudo parted-ls` or `lsusb`.

You are my last resort, therefore, any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I observe a similar behavior on a (dual-boot Win 10/Ubuntu 18.04) HP Spectre X360:

When using the Sandisk Extreme 128GB under Windows it works flawlessly, but trying to mount it under Ubuntu fails.

An interesting solution in my case was the usage of an USB-C adapter (USBC->HDMI,Card Reader, Network, USB3). After inserting the card into the card slot of this adapter instead of inserting it directly into the accoring PC-slot, Ubuntu was able to mount the card without any problems.